# How to invoke some code once after and additional to a Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Imagine having this code running in a Thread:

```
while (blockingQueue.size() > 0) {
    
    AbortableCountDownLatch latch = (AbortableCountDownLatch) blockingQueue.poll();
    latch.countDown();
}
Thread.sleep(updateinterval * 1000);
```

How to make the while loop run after the Thread.sleep as an additional execution? As something like:

```
Thread.sleepAndExecute(Runnable code, sleep time);
```

So that the code is just executed, after the sleep has entered, not the other way around?

The blockingQueue contains some CountDownLatch, which are blocking another thread. The other thread just is allowed to continue, IF the latches are all countdown AND this thread has entered sleep/await state. Both conditions need to be true so that the other thread is allowed to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you should not be needing to sleep. You can use CompleteableFurture API thenCombine to combine the two tasks. Code below

```
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            while (blockingQueue.size() > 0) {
                try {
                   System.out.println("Sleeping in thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                   Thread.sleep(1000l);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })
        .thenCombine( CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
            System.out.println("Polling in thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            while (blockingQueue.size() > 0) {

                AbortableCountDownLatch latch = blockingQueue.poll();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }), (i, j) -> null);
```

Both sleep and latchdown happens in different threads.

```
Sleeping in thread - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19
Polling in thread - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
Sleeping in thread - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19
```

CompletionStages implements producer-consumer with the help of two stages chained using *Async API and passing the executor with blocking queue. I think that should be the best fit for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is really nice! I learned something new today, this actually shows why I love Java so much. Java 8 still has a lot of (amazing) mechanics it seems I didnt know so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)'s `thenApply` method as a callback to `supplyAsync`.

As the name suggests, `supplyAsync` takes a `Supplier<T>` as an argument, while `thenApply` takes a `Function<T,R>`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> futureText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return "waited one second";
}).thenApply(input-> {
    // run some code as an additional execution
    return "inside thenApply, " + input;
});

System.out.println(futureText.get()); // prints: inside thenApply, waited one second
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where is this different than the code above? The result is the same, and not what I want. I want the Thread.sleep been executed. But then additional execute the other code, with no block of the thread itself in between. The latches need to be countdown addition to the sleep, not blocking thread1, and thread2 needs to just continue, when latches are all countdown and thread1 is in sleep state. Like I said, I need something like Thread.SleepPLUSOneExecutionAfterSleepInitiation. Not after AfterSleepIsFinished.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add sleep in a different thread. Either you can use completeable future or Executor Service.

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit( () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000l);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        while (blockingQueue.size() > 0) {

            AbortableCountDownLatch latch = blockingQueue.poll();
            latch.countDown();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: Ive already come to the conclusion, to use another thread, to check in a while loop for the other thread is in Thread.state.TIME_WAITING with a 50ms sleep check while loop, but I find this a really dirty solution. Is there no other way like I said above? Some sort of DoSomething (put the own thread to sleep) but then do one more command directly after the other, thenApply, like the above? But which could be used in this case? Also what is the meaning in shutting down an Executor btw if you wont use them anyway anymore? Wont a shutdown interference with the asks which might run a long time?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to enter the sleep and then execute something else in parallel.  What is the purpose of the sleep block? Is it just waiting to drain the blocking queue? If so, I am not sure why thenApply is not the right solution because it will automatically chain the operations one after another. I just used ExecutorService shutdown as the program won't terminate otherwise.

Comment: Ive tried your solution with the CompletableFuture, it doesnt work. The moment Thread.sleep is called, it stops/blocks in that thread, and the thenApply is never called. Like I said. I need something like Thread.sleepAndExecute(Runnable code, sleep time); Not sure how I should explain it else. The thread in which this is called should go into sleep BUT do one last thing, after the sleep is initiated properly. I need this as a event fire, that the thread is entered a proper sleep state. thread.sleep(n) blocks. sleep=true;thread.sleep(n) is not thread safe / wrong order.